# UINavigationBar animation incorrectly handling view's frame in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios7

I've encountered a weird situation with UINavigationBar in iOS7 and i was wondering if anyone had come across this/found a solution.

I've got a UINavigationController with another UIViewController with a tableview taking up the whole view (added in nib) embedded as the rootViewController. The UINavigationController's navBar's translucent property is set to NO. More on that later. The root controller contains this code:

```
[self.navigationItem setPrompt:@"My Prompt Text"];
```

This causes the UINavigationBar to be enlarged in order to fit the text. Thats fine.

When I push a new view controller that does not set the prompt property, the navigation bar animates to its smaller size, yet it does not adjust the frame of my tableview (also the bounds of the view, and also added via a nib). So I've got this black space that now exists btwn the bottom of my navigation bar and the top of my table view.

Similarly, when I navigate back, the navigation bar animates back to its larger size to accommodate the prompt, and now overlaps my tableview's frame.

Now, if i go back and set the translucent property on the navigation bar to YES, everything works as desired. What gives?

Comment: What is the edgesForExtendedLayout property on the view controller set to?

Comment: didn't set them explicitly so UIRectEdgeAll i'd think

Comment: If you're seeing a black space, I'm guessing that's the UIWindow peaking through, or is there a view with a black background somewhere in the view hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently a nib's simulated metrics have an effect on the way the view hierarchy lays itself out. I assumed that we'd resolve that stuff at runtime, but i guess not.

Fixed this issue by changing the simulated metrics in the nib to show an opaque status bar.

Comment: Anybody know how to fix this for views created in code, rather than from a nib?